# How to fill select options based on previous select?

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm trying to get the hang of Forms'N'Ajax in Drupal 8.

I have a classic problem with my selects in D8:

```
$form['manufactureYear'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Manufacture year'),
  '#options' => $manufactureYears,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => array($this, 'populateDurationYears'),
    'wrapper' => 'edit-loanDurationYears'
  ],
);
```

Then I have a second select:

```
$form['loanDurationYears'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Loan duration years'),
);
```

The function **populateDurationYears** is the one that are killing me. I've tried with the ReplaceCommand in a AjaxResponse, but when I submit the form the *loanDurationYears* select is empty.

Can somebody help me here?

**EDIT:**
 - If I change *ReplaceCommand* with *AppendCommand* it's almost correct. The code now looks like this:

```
<select id="edit-loandurationyears" class="form-select" name="loanDurationYears" data-drupal-selector="edit-loandurationyears">
  <div>
    <option value="3">3 years</option>
    <option value="4">4 years</option>
    <option value="5">5 years</option>
    <option value="6">6 years</option>
    <option value="7">7 years</option>
    <option value="8">8 years</option>
    <option value="9">9 years</option>
  </div>
</select>
```

What's up with that `<div>`? It messes up the select :-(

**EDIT 2:**

The populateDurationYears method looks like this:

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();
if($maxDurationYears != 0) {
  for($i = $minLoanDurationYears-1; $i < $maxDurationYears; $i++) {
    $option .= "<option value='" . (string)($i+1) . "'>" . (string)($i+1) . " år</option>";
  }
  $response->addCommand(new AppendCommand('#edit-loandurationyears', $option));
}
return $response;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out on how to do this...

I fill out the #options for the second `<select>` when I build the form.
I hide it with a #states.

When the user then selects something in the first `<select>` I use the populateDurationYears method to remove invalid options like this:

```
$options = [];
if($maxDurationYears != 0) {
  for($i = $minLoanDurationYears-1; $i < $maxDurationYears; $i++) {
    $options[] = ($i+1) . " years";
  }
  $form['loanDurationYears']['#options'] = $options;
}
return $form['loanDurationYears'];
```

This does the trick :-) No need for AjaxResponse or anything like the ReplaceCommand etc... Keep it simpel Stupid! ;-)

Comment: I think you shoud mark this (your own) answer as accepted ...

Comment: can you share the full code ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `#prefix` and `#suffix` to add a wrapper around $form['loanDurationYears']. Your code would look like this:

```
$form['manufactureYear'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Manufacture year'),
  '#options' => $manufactureYears,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => array($this, 'populateDurationYears'),
    'wrapper' => 'loanduration-wrapper'
  ],
);

$form['loanDurationYears'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Loan duration years'),
  '#prefix' => '<div id="loanduration-wrapper">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

Comment: it still gives the DIV tag inside the SELECT tag? The OPTION tags are there - but the DIV messes it up :-(

Comment: Do you get the same results if you use `ReplaceCommand` instead of `AppendCommand`?

Comment: The ReplaceCommand completly removes the `<select>` tag with the `option` tags.

Comment: I figured it out by myself - thank you very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

The drupal core ajax.js will check the number of elements inside the string you pass to the response. The div container will only be added if you pass more than 1 element. Adding one option at a time will prevent this behaviour. In your case the correct way to go by ajax would be:

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();
if($maxDurationYears != 0) {
  for($i = $minLoanDurationYears-1; $i < $maxDurationYears; $i++) {
    $option = "<option value='" . (string)($i+1) . "'>" . (string)($i+1) . " år</option>";
    $response->addCommand(new AppendCommand('#edit-loandurationyears', $option));
  }
}
return $response;
```